# How to rename folder on cloud disk in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-storage

I use Laravel 8 with this code:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

// ...

Storage::disk('aws')->rename($old_path, $new_uri);
```

But it doesn't work.

I tried to do this too, but also not worked:

```php
Storage::disk('aws')->move($old_path, $new_uri);
```

Any idea how can I rename a folder on a disk in Laravel?

Comment: It should work. 
Post the error here (update question).

Maybe the problem with paths.

Comment: I have no error message. I get back `200 OK`. But the folder isn't renamed.